# Alter Minimum Bounding Box Algorithm

Tags: python, pyqgis, geometry

I'm trying to create an algorithm similar to minimum bounding box (though it may end up looking nothing like it). In this case the angle will be passed as a parameter and given the angle I need the smallest rectangle covering all my points/polygons. So far my line of thought is to find the center of my points (centroid algorithm), and from there create two parallel lines with same angle as paramter angle, and two more lines perpendicular to them. Then using iteration move these lines outwards (in opposite directions) until they contain all points. Also doesn't have to be exact minimum bounding box, approximate works (I guess would depend on size of each iteration step).

Here is my code so far. I have already dissolved all my polygons into one. I then take a convex hull to reduce vertices. I then put all vertices in a list - not sure if this helps yet...

```
a = layer.getFeatures()
for feat in a:
    geom = feat.geometry()
a = geom.convexHull()
vertexId = QgsVertexId()
vertices = []
b = a.constGet().nextVertex(vertexId)
while b[0]:
    vertices.append(b[1])
    b = a.constGet().nextVertex(vertexId)
```

Notes: At some point I need to pass the angle of box. I am using QGIS 3, and need to create this in Python. Layer 'layer' has one geometry, the dissolved polygon of all other polygons - maybe iteration isn't needed to access it..

Please let me know if I should be passing on more details/info.

Comment: This is straight forward task. Rotate vertices of convex hull using standard equations, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104611/find-new-coordinates-of-a-point-after-rotation Compute minX, minY etc. Unrotate and create rectangle of 4 xy pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is the complete code.](https://github.com/cesarkero/QGIS_scripts/blob/master/QGIS_3.8_console/RotatedMinBoundingBox.py) It contains too many lines (much more than needed for sure) but it works. Now you can clean it if you like.

In resume the algorithm calculates the maximum distance betweeen parallel lines that have the slope defined by the rotation parameter and pass though the points. For each point there will be created a 'horizontal' and 'vertical' line. This names are just orientative as they are defined at position 0 (rotation = 0). So, for each external point there will be created this 2 posible lines and then, iteratively, the poligon will be created based on the 4 external, or said in other way, where the distance of parallel lines are maximum.

One last thing: it is made to be used in QGIS 3.8 with grass.

[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from processing.tools import *
from qgis.utils import iface
import qgis.utils, os, glob, processing, string, time, shutil, ogr

#PARAMETERS AND LAYERS
rotation = 45 #use any value between 0 and <90 #90 would make a mess

layer1 = iface.activeLayer() # Load the layer (from active)
crs = layer1.crs().authid() #get crs

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#LINE EQUATIONS
''' 
BASIC LINE EQUATIONS
y = ax + b
a = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
b = y1 - a * x1
Distance = (| a*x1 + b*y1 + c |) / (sqrt( a*a + b*b))# Function to find straight distance betweeen line and point 
'''
# slope from angle
def sfa (a):
    return round(math.tan(math.radians(a)),12) #round to avoid problems with horizontal and vertical

# angle from slope (not used)
def afs (s):
    return (math.atan(s) / math.pi) * 180

# Function to find distance 
def shortest_distance(x1, y1, a, b, c):    
    d = round(abs((a * x1 + b * y1 + c)) / (math.sqrt(a * a + b * b)) , 12)
    return d

# Function to find interception between lines
def cross(a1,b1,a2,b2):
    x = (b2-b1) / (a1-a2)
    y = a1 * x + b1
    return (x,y)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# GET LIST OF POINTS TO ITERATE
# Calculate convexhull to reduce the iterations between point
# This avoid calculations on 'internal' points
# process of minimum bounding geometry convexHull
MBG = processing.run("qgis:minimumboundinggeometry", {'INPUT': layer1,'FIELD':None,'TYPE':3,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})

# Get vertex of MBG
MBGp = processing.run("native:extractvertices", {'INPUT':MBG['OUTPUT'],'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})

plist = list(MBGp['OUTPUT'].getFeatures())

lp = list()
for p in plist:
    geom = p.geometry()
    a = geom.asPoint()
    point = (a[0],a[1])
    lp.append(point)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# PROCESS
# compare hdist and v dist betweeen each pair of point and get the most distant lines
hdist_max = 0
vdist_max = 0
index = list(range(0,len(lp))) #iteration index
bl = ['ah1','bh1','av1','bv1','ah2','bh2','av2','bv2'] #polygon lines defined by 8 parameters see below

for i in index[:-1]:
    print('i'+str(i))
    for t in index[i+1:]:
        print('t'+str(t))

        x1 = lp[i][0] #; print('x1: {}', x1)
        y1 = lp[i][1] #; print('y1: {}', y1)
        x2 = lp[t][0] #; print('x2: {}', x2)
        y2 = lp[t][1] #; print('y2: {}', y2)

        #h1 equation
        ah1 = sfa(rotation)
        bh1 = y1 - ah1 * x1

        #v1 equation
        av1 = sfa(rotation + 90) #remember that just the horizontal is the reference at 0 rotation
        bv1 = y1 - av1 * x1 

        #h2 equation
        ah2 = sfa(rotation)
        bh2 = y2 - ah2 * x2

        #v2 equation
        av2 = sfa(rotation + 90) #remember that just the horizontal is the reference
        bv2 = y2 - av2 * x2 

        # H dist
        hdist = shortest_distance(x1, y1, ah2, -1, bh2)
        vdist = shortest_distance(x1, y1, av2, -1, bv2)

        if hdist > hdist_max:
            bl[0] = ah1
            bl[1] = bh1
            bl[4] = ah2
            bl[5] = bh2
            hdist_max = hdist #update max hdist
        if vdist > vdist_max:
            bl[2] = av1
            bl[3] = bv1
            bl[6] = av2
            bl[7] = bv2
            vdist_max = vdist #update max vdist

print("Max perpendicular distance betweeen 'horizontal lines' is",hdist_max, ' m')
print("Max perpendicular distance betweeen 'verticallines' is",vdist_max, ' m')

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# GET 4 COORDS FROM BOUNDINGLINES bl
# using the slope and intercept from boundinglines can we now calculate the 4 corners of the rotated polygon
H1V1 = cross(bl[0],bl[1],bl[2],bl[3]) # H1V1
H1V2 = cross(bl[0],bl[1],bl[6],bl[7]) # H1V2
H2V1 = cross(bl[4],bl[5],bl[2],bl[3]) # H2V1
H2V2 = cross(bl[4],bl[5],bl[6],bl[7]) # H2V2

# SORT POINTS CLOCKWISE AND CREATE QgsPointXY for polygon
clist = [H1V1,H1V2,H2V1,H2V2]
points=[]
points.append(sorted(clist, key=lambda e: (e[1], e[0]))[0]); clist.remove(points[0]) #minX and minY
points.append(sorted(clist, key=lambda e: (e[0], e[1]))[0]); clist.remove(points[1]) #minY and minX
points.append(sorted(clist, key=lambda e: (e[1]), reverse=True)[0]); clist.remove(points[2]) #maxY
points.append(clist[0]) #remaining
p=[]
for i in points:
    p.append(QgsPointXY(i[0],i[1]))
print('Coords of the polygon: ',p)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#CREATE ROTATED BOUNDING BOX FROM THESE POINTS
layer = QgsVectorLayer(str('Polygon?crs='+crs), 'polygon' , 'memory')
prov = layer.dataProvider()
feat = QgsFeature()
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([p]))
prov.addFeatures([feat])
layer.updateExtents()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
```